# Impossible to connect to server through SSH with Filezilla

Tags: ssh, ftp, filezilla

I have a Debian server which had a HDD failure and was re-installed identically (same hostname, same IP, same distro).

I used to be able to connect via SSH using Filezilla from my Ubuntu desktop but since the server was re-installed, I get the following error:

```
Status :    Connecting to xxxxx.xxxxx.com:22...<br />
Response :  fzSftp started<br />
Command :   open "xxxxx@xxxxx.com" 22<br />
Error : Server unexpectedly closed network connection<br />
Error : Impossible to establish connection to server
```

I suspect fzSftp refuses to connect because the server fingerprint has changed but I don't know how to delete the old record in order to accept the new one.

The worst thing is that I am able to connect with Filezilla from a Windows computer without any problem!

Please help me, I already spent hours trying to fix it and it is really anoying!

Edit: 
I already tried to uninstall/reinstall filezilla, clear cache, delete filezilla hidden files (in user profile)... without success.
I have no problem to connect using regular FTP and I have no problem connecting SSH via the console.

Comment: try to connect using normal `sftp` from commandline and get verbose log (`sftp -vvv host`). You should be able to see the reason for rejecting.

Comment: @Jakuje:  I did connect from commnad line as suggested and I connected succesfully. So I tried with filezilla again but no luck ! At least we are sure the problem comes from filezilla (probably fzSftp)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Error : Server unexpectedly closed network connection
> ```
>
> ...
>   I suspect fzSftp refuses to connect because the server fingerprint has changed

I doubt this. The servers fingerprint is checked by the client and thus the client would close the connection if the fingerprint does not match. But in this case obviously the server closes the connection, which indicates either that the server does not like the client or that the server has a problem by itself.

> The worst thing is that I am able to connect with Filezilla from a Windows computer without any problem!

Then I recommend that you check the difference in the setups. For example it would be possible that you use FTP/FTPS on Windows but not SFTP (i.e. SSH) like you try on the Ubuntu desktop. Or it could be that you use a different password or username. Or that there are restrictions on the server side from which IP address a connection is possible, that there is a firewall in between your client and the server .... You might get some more information when looking at the log files at the server side.

Comment: No difference in setting in filezilla between Windows and Ubuntu machine. Same public IP. BTW I can connect via FTP mode on both machines.

Comment: @David: then I recommend to have a look at the logs on the server side and compare the logs from successful with unsuccessful connections.